# "Could not copy Mosaico Template' in 4.7.20

Tags: civimail, mosaico

I upgraded to 4.7.20 and am now unable to copy Mosaico templates. I also get strange behaviour when I try to edit a template. On clicking 'edit' CiviCRM displays 'Configure your Dashboard' and displays a Chrome print dialog box.
Is anyone else seeing the same behaviour?

Comment: Would help if you confirm the version of Mosaico. Latest?

Comment: Mosaico extension is version 1.0 and has been working well until CiviCRM 4.7.20.

Comment: we are running all ours on 2-beta

Comment: I was going to wait until it was released but maybe I should install it now and see if that solves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is resolved by upgrading to Mosaico Version 2.0 beta2.